# Cannot used functions defined in header file

Tags: c, header, header-files, function-declaration

My source file starts with:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

I am able to use all of my global variables, types, and structs from my header file.  In my header file i started with a couple of includes:

```
#include<file.h>
```

Then move on to global variables:

```
#define GLOBAL
```

Then structs:

```
#typedef struct boo;
```

Then types.  Then i go to function declarations. I.E:

```
size_t foo(int*r, size_t nitems);
```

What am I doing wrong that i am getting linker errors>

Comment: I cannot help but wonder what the #define GLOBAL is for?

Comment: The #define global is just a global varibale definition, I have written:
#define Global 5
But i am getting a LNK2001

Comment: Please distill your program to a minimal, complete sample the demonstrates the problem and post that here, along with whatever compiler and linker errors it produces. For information about how to do that, and why it is important, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: You are including the header files, so the objects compile. But you need to include libraries for the objects to link to for the system (<>) header files with a -l compiler switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's presumably in how you're linking.

Answer (score 1):

The header file provides the function declaration to your source code.  As you've found that's enough to get your code to compile but not to get it to link.

To get it to link you have to provide the linker with a file containing the actual compiled function - the function declaration is effectively a promise to the compiler that you will do this.

Exactly how you do it depends on what tools you're using and what form the compiled function is in.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` for simple substitution identifiers works exactly like a copy/paste.

After you do

```
#define GLOBAL 5
```

the following code

```
int GLOBAL;
GLOBAL = 13;
putchar(GLOBAL);
```

gets transformed to

```
int 5;
5 = 13;
putchar(5);
```

which obviously does not compile.